# Telegram API: cannot update Webhook

Tags: api, bots, telegram

So initially I created a `webHook`with `allowed_updates = ['message']` only.

And now I cannot receive any updates except private bot messages (obviously)

I tried to `deleteWebhook`, create it again with `allowed_updates = ['message', 'channel_post']` etc , deleting and creating again with new **url endpoint** but unsuccessfuly.

`getWebhookInfo` still return `"allowed_updates":["message"]`

Answer (score 0):

Token revoking was helped 
( I did it via BotFather, with new token webhook was updated successfull)
Thanks